# Deleting an object created with "new"

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, segmentation-fault

Objects from my class `Note` are stored by keeping a pointer in a list called `m_noteList`:

```
QList< QSharedPointer<Note> > m_noteList;
```

I am creating an object of that class by:

```
QSharedPointer<Note> note(new Note(this));
m_noteList << note;
```

Deleting goes by (after getting the right index `idx` to identify the object):

```
delete m_noteList[idx].data();
```

Error message in QtCreator (Debug-mode)

```
HEAP[MyApp.exe]: 
HEAP: Free Heap block 024FC240 modified at 02500330 after it was freed
```

And dissambler:

```
0x777349ab  <+0x0000>         cmpb   $0x0,0x2(%eax)
0x777349af  <+0x0000>         je     0x777349c6
0x777349b1  <+0x0000>         movb   $0x1,0x7774d640
0x777349b8  <+0x0000>         mov    %ecx,0x7774d644
0x777349be  <+0x0000>         int3
0x777349bf  <+0x0000>         movb   $0x0,0x7774d640   //<-- Here is a stop mark
0x777349c6  <+0x0000>         ret
0x777349c7  <+0x0000>         nop
...
```

I have also tried this:

```
m_noteList.removeAt(idx);
```

Which does not work either. `SIGSEGV` signal emitted by operating system stopped the process (Segmentation fault)

So I really don't know what I do wrong and how to get around it

My solution is quite dirty: Setting some kind of an `deleted`-tag to my objects, but I  need to check this in every other function to ignore that object...

EDIT:

I realised one thing: If i delete one note (with `removeAt()`), it is deleted (i see it by watching the console print outputs), but its gui does not disappear. Then if I click again on that object's specific button that is to delete the note, the application crashes (because it does not really exist any more, but only the gui). But if I write this `deleteLater` before, after deleting it, the gui also disappears and everything seems fine.
Can someone please explain, why?

```
m_noteList.at(idx)->deleteLater();
m_noteList.removeAt(idx);
```

Comment: You're not supposed to `delete` the resources managed by a `QSharedPointer`.

Comment: So how should I delete it, or can I possibly create a `QList<Note>`without the `QSharedPointer`? Not sure if I really need it.

Comment: Deletion happens automatically once there are no shared pointers handling the same resource. That is the point (no pun intended) of a shared pointer.

Comment: But this is the only pointer to the object in my whole application

Comment: Then it will get deleted whenever the shared pointer goes out of scope. But shared pointers are for shared ownership. If you don't have shared ownership, you don't need a shared pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza That's not entirely true, since you can't really put a `QScopedPointer` or a `std::unique_ptr` in a Qt container, or much any container in fact. Only C++11 containers that support `emplace_back` support this. For storing pointers in containers, a `QSharedPointer` is the only solution.

Comment: @KubaOber That may be, but it is really a hack, an abuse of a shared pointer, because it can lead to situations where the resource ends up being shared.

Comment: @juanchopanza Who cares if the resource ends up shared? Either you copy the pointers around, and when using raw pointers you'd have an unchecked dangling pointer, or you don't, and then the pointer is not really shared at all. The use of a shared pointer ensures safety no matter what, and that's the point.

Comment: @KubaOber I would care. If I don't want shared ownership then I don't want to allow it. Throwing shared pointers at any memory management problem is not a good solution.

Comment: I guess the main question is: why don't you simply store `Note` instances in the list? Internally, `QList` stores pointers to instances *anyway*.

Comment: I tried to use `QList<Note* > *m_noteList` but get instantly a `segmentation fault` error on appending the objects to the list. If I use `QList<Note* > m_noteList` instead, creating (appending) seems to work, but deleting by `removeAt` causes the segfault error.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up **three** memory management strategies:

1. `QObject` parent-child memory management: when a parent `QObject` is deleted, it automatically deletes all child `QObjects`. Explained [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#dtor.QObject). Deleting the object is done automatically, so explicit deletion is not necessary.
2. `QSharedPointer` memory management: when the last `QSharedPointer` referring to an object is deleted, the object is deleted. Explained [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsharedpointer.html#details). The object is deleted automatically, so explicit deletion is not necessary.
3. "Manual" memory management: `new` an object and `delete` an object at the right time. Explained in the C++ standard. The object must be deleted manually.

You should select only one of the above to make sure you don't double-delete objects. I suggest choosing between #1 and #2 depending on how you plan to use the objects. If you plan to share the objects across "parents", use #2, otherwise use #1.

Answer (score 0):

Given a `QList<QSharedPointer<Note>> m_noteList`:

The deletion of the `Note` object is accomplished by `m_noteList.removeAt(idx)`, assuming that there are no other extant copies of the pointer. You simply destruct the last shared pointer to a given note, and that's it. Invoking `delete` on a shared pointer's data is *always an error*.

I cannot reproduce your issue with `removeAt` - it will only happen if you `delete` the Note first, which you're not supposed to do.

Comment: Well, I think that, technically, deleting a pointer twice is considered *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Jefffrey Or, in plain language, an error :) People get routinely confused since they don't recognize the all-important difference between undefined- and implementation-defined behavior. An error is succinct and to the point :)

Comment: The standard doesn't say anything about errors in this case. With undefined behavior, according to the standard, anything could happen. Even that you get killed by a unicorn. So, yeah, don't do undefined behavior. :)

Comment: @Jefffrey Committing an error has plain English meaning that has nothing to do with programming language standards. It is an error to write C++ code that has undefined behavior. It's as simple as that. An error doesn't imply diagnostic or anything like that. Erroneous human behavior it is.